# Why one function crashes, but a similiar one doesn't?

Tags: concurrency, vulkan, compute-shader

I'm trying to synchronise multiple workgroups in a shader, like with a barrier. Specification doesn't seem to provide any guarrantes about execution fairness between workgroups, but it appears that implementations usually schedule threads at least semi-fairly - if at least a single command was executed, others will be, with some quirks regarding warp divergence. I recall reading in AMD whitepaper that they prioritise threads that haven't been executed for longest, and nVidia has a [presentation](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2013/presentations/S3101-Atomic-Memory-Operations.pdf) that uses spinlock for locks.

With this I have 3 variables in global memory that help in creating this barrier:

1. `threadsActive`, which counts how many threads started execution
2. `threadsReached`, which counts how many threads reached last barrier
3. `threadsPhase`, which counts how many barriers have been passed through already - so that late threads don't do unneeded work

I have these functions as barriers(note that `gl_WorkGroupSize.yz` are equal to 1):

```c
bool barrierGrid(uint phase){
    if(threadsPhase >  phase)return false; //the block after the barrier is already completed
    if(threadsPhase == phase)return true;  //currently being completed
    barrier();                             //makes sure all threads in a block have come this far
    if(gl_LocalInvocationIndex == 0){      //picks a representative thread
                                           //if all active threads have come this far, pick the last thread
        if(threadsActive == atomicAdd(threadsReached, gl_WorkGroupSize.x)+gl_WorkGroupSize.x){
            threadsReached = 0;            // prepare for next barrier
            memoryBarrierBuffer();         // it is prepared before other threads run wild
            threadsPhase = phase;          // release the threads
        }
        while(threadsPhase < phase)
            memoryBarrierBuffer();         //wait until all threads come
    }
    barrier();                             //make threads wait for the representative
    return true;
}

bool barrierGridSub(uint phase){
    if(threadsPhase >  phase)return false;
    if(threadsPhase == phase)return true;
    subgroupBarrier();
    if(subgroupElect()){
        if(threadsActive == atomicAdd(threadsReached, gl_SubgroupSize)+gl_SubgroupSize){
            threadsReached = 0; 
            memoryBarrierBuffer(); 
            threadsPhase = phase;
        }
        while(threadsPhase < phase)
            memoryBarrierBuffer();
    }
    subgroupBarrier();
    return true;
}
```

Where `barrierGrid()` picks a representative thread per workgroup, and `barrierGridSub()` picks a representative per subgroup.

However, only the `barrierGridSub()` works - the `barrierGrid()` version makes the driver timeout and crash. Synchronising threads one by one also works, but ~1.5 slower than subgroup-wise. I fail to see any difference between those two functions which would cause one to fail completely.

I would have expected the `barrierGrid()` to work potentially better due to lower amount of atomics (although probably the most of atomics cost comes from shuffling memory between SMs, in which case the HW could probably group them making the cost difference negligeble)...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. As far as the Vulkan specification is concerned, this will not work. At all. The Vulkan memory model provides *zero* fairness guarantees, and there's no way to synchronize between different work groups of the same compute shader dispatch. So... do you want something that maybe works on some hardware, or what?

Comment: Yep. If it works on some hardware (like my fairly average GPU), it would be fine. And it does work, in at least one case (and I recall reading a paper that tested it on other HW). What I want is to know what in using `gl_LocalInvocationIndex == 0` instead of `subgroupElect()` breaks it

Comment: Where is `phase` set and how is that synchronized? The obvious difference is the initial `barrier()` vs `subgroupBarrier()`; the former being "real" and the second being mostly a no-op. If updates to `phase` are not synchronized safely across the workgroup then some subgroups return from the return checks before the first `barrier()` and some hit the `barrier()` so it deadlocks.